# C++,Android | SDL and OpenGL ES (nothing drawn)

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, sdl

I want to use booth SDL and gles 1 on Android using a native activity.
SDL offers a function to create an OpenGL-context( SDL_GL_CreateContext ).
Clearing the screen and swapping the buffer works, but every draw-attempt fails.
To make sure, that i made nothing wrong, i made the drawing-attempt as small as possible.
Here is the small sample.

```
// creating OpengGL-context [...]

while (true) // basic mainloop
{
    // set viewport and projectionmatrix
    glViewport(0, 0, engine->getWidth(), engine->getHeight()); // width and height in pixels

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrthof(-1, 1, 1,  -1, -1.0, 1.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    //draw shape
    GLfloat vertices[] = {1,0,0, 0,1,0, -1,0,0};
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}

// free memory [...]
```

The problem is now that nothing is drawn. But my OpenGL-context is valid.

Any help would be appreciated :)
Thanks

Edit:
I actually forgot to force OpenGL 1, using

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);
```

Comment: Don't you have to call some SDL function at the end of the main loop to tell it that the frame is finished? The tutorials I have seen normally call something like `SDL_GL_SwapBuffers`. Also, you're going to overflow the matrix stack quickly since you call `glPushMatrix()` in each loop, but never `glPopMatrix()`.

Comment: Yes, I call SDL_GL_SwapBuffer(), but I forgot to include it in the sample.

Comment: Oh and thanks. I didnt recognized the matrix-overflow

Comment: Okay, I recognized, that I havent forced OpenGL 1, which is needed, when using OpenGL 1.